OData Source - Dynamically Add the dates using SSIS
I need Last 7 days of records using Odata Source in SSIS. Already Test it with Now() function but it is not working. Data part should be dynamically(like now()-7 if I am passing manually then it working but dynamically option is not working.
My Date format is '2024-07-29 18:43:30.730 on source.
I am using below query in ODataSource in SSIS.
$filter=StartDate gt datetime now()-1 and Status eq 'Final'
I already check with Now function and other option to define the startdata and endate in variable and then try to use it in odata source using SSIS but still it is not working.
I want to update it odatasource in Query option.
